# Open Loop Transfer Function and Stability?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Given the following open loop transfer function
$$G_{OL} = \frac{k}{(s+1)^2(0.5s + 1)^2}e^{-\tau s}$$

Let $k = k_{max}/2$. Let $\tau_{max}$ denote the value of the parameter $\tau$ such that the system in a unity negative feedback loop is stable for $\tau < \tau_{max}$. Find $\tau_{max}$

I know $k_{max} = 9/2$ from applying the Routh Hurwitz stability criterion with $\tau = 0$, so $k = 9/4$ in this case.

**Questions:**

How do I determine $\tau_{max}$? I can expand $G_{OL}$ find the magnitude and phase, approximate a Bode plot or make a Nyquist plot, but how does this help? I should also be able to find the closed-loop transfer function since its unity negative feedback. I guess I just don't see the connection between the tools (Bode, root locus, Nyquist) used to analyze stability and actually finding $\tau_{max}$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you expand on the definition of $\tau_\text{max}$, especially with unity negative feedback do you mean $k=1$?

Comment: I suspect it would be hard to give a precise answer here? Presumably $t_\max $ should be $\tau_\max$? Perhaps you could plot (Nyquist) $G_\text{OL}$ and increase $\tau$ until the curve touches $-1$?

Comment: My apologies! Yes, that was a typo (up too late) I changed it to $\tau_{\max}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find $\tau_{max}$ as the delay margin. Set $\tau=0$, find the phase margin and the corresponding frequency. Then compute for which $\tau$ the phase shift induced by the delay will be equal to the phase margin.

Comment: This is a nice estimate, but what gives confidence that there is no smaller $\tau$ for which $G_\text{CL}$ is unstable?

Comment: @copper.hat you can interpret it via the Nyquist criterion. Another way is to consider the roots of the closed-loop system denominator. These roots are continuous in $\tau$, and thus they must cross the imaginary axes for some $\tau$ before getting a positive real part.